# class 'psycopg2.InterfaceError': connection already closed

Tags: django, postgresql, connection, fastcgi, flup

I am pulling my hair over this and am about ready to do something dirty.

I am running nginx + django + postgresql. Half the time I am trying to test my site and open a page, I get the following:

```
<class 'psycopg2.InterfaceError'>   Python 2.7.2: /home/webapp/newavenue/bin/python
Fri Feb 24 08:28:58 2012
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

 /home/webapp/newavenue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py in run(self=<flup.server.fcgi_base.Request object>)
    572             
    573         try:
=>  574             protocolStatus, appStatus = self.server.handler(self)
    575         except:
    576             traceback.print_exc(file=self.stderr)
protocolStatus undefined, appStatus undefined, self = <flup.server.fcgi_base.Request object>, self.server = <flup.server.fcgi_fork.WSGIServer object>, self.server.handler = <bound method WSGIServer.handler of <flup.server.fcgi_fork.WSGIServer object>>
 /home/webapp/newavenue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py in handler(self=<flup.server.fcgi_fork.WSGIServer object>, req=<flup.server.fcgi_base.Request object>)
   1157         try:
   1158             try:
=> 1159                 result = self.application(environ, start_response)
   1160                 try:
   1161                     for data in result:
result = None, self = <flup.server.fcgi_fork.WSGIServer object>, self.application = <django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object>, environ = {'CONTENT_LENGTH': '', 'CONTENT_TYPE': '', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate,sdch', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'csrftoken=8a0176b368b17af00a8563b5f95b134b; sess...e5bdd0d0a4e3092e7a9abd0029c02; django_language=en', 'HTTP_HOST': 'newavedev.zapto.org', ...}, start_response = <function start_response>
 /home/webapp/newavenue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py in __call__(self=<django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object>, environ={'CONTENT_LENGTH': '', 'CONTENT_TYPE': '', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate,sdch', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'csrftoken=8a0176b368b17af00a8563b5f95b134b; sess...e5bdd0d0a4e3092e7a9abd0029c02; django_language=en', 'HTTP_HOST': 'newavedev.zapto.org', ...}, start_response=<function start_response>)
    272                 response = self.get_response(request)
    273         finally:
=>  274             signals.request_finished.send(sender=self.__class__)
    275 
    276         try:
global signals = <module 'django.core.signals' from '/home/webapp...python2.7/site-packages/django/core/signals.pyc'>, signals.request_finished = <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object>, signals.request_finished.send = <bound method Signal.send of <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object>>, sender undefined, self = <django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object>, self.__class__ = <class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler'>
 /home/webapp/newavenue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py in send(self=<django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object>, sender=<class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler'>, **named={})
    170 
    171         for receiver in self._live_receivers(_make_id(sender)):
=>  172             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
    173             responses.append((receiver, response))
    174         return responses
response undefined, receiver = <function close_connection>, signal undefined, self = <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object>, sender = <class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler'>, named = {}
 /home/webapp/newavenue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py in close_connection(**kwargs={'sender': <class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler'>, 'signal': <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object>})
     83 def close_connection(**kwargs):
     84     for conn in connections.all():
=>   85         conn.close()
     86 signals.request_finished.connect(close_connection)
     87 
conn = <django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.base.DatabaseWrapper object>, conn.close = <bound method DatabaseWrapper.close of <django.d...postgresql_psycopg2.base.DatabaseWrapper object>>
 /home/webapp/newavenue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py in close(self=<django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.base.DatabaseWrapper object>)
    242     def close(self):
    243         if self.connection is not None:
=>  244             self.connection.close()
    245             self.connection = None
    246 
self = <django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.base.DatabaseWrapper object>, self.connection = <connection object at 0x1d37130; dsn: 'dbname=ne...er=postgres host=localhost port=5432', closed: 2>, self.connection.close = <built-in method close of psycopg2._psycopg.connection object>
<class 'psycopg2.InterfaceError'>: connection already closed 
      args = ('connection already closed',) 
      cursor = None 
      message = 'connection already closed' 
      pgcode = None 
      pgerror = None
```

The server is run with the following to generate the preceding flup traceback report:

```
python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8000 debug=False
```

Could I just get around this by patching in something like: "try: self.connection.close(), except: pass" around that offending line? It would probably work but I think it sounds dirty (messing with core) and I would like to try to find an alternative solution.

Edit: Considering this guy's approach too: commenting it out: http://osdir.com/ml/DjangoUsers/2009-04/msg01647.html

Comment: I had a similar error a while ago, can't remember if it was the same thing, but the problem was that a new version of psycopg was released and was incompatible. Try downgrading psycopg. If that's not possible try the django 1.4beta or maybe just the pg db module from 1.4beta.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got around the problem. This is not really a solution to the flup-psycopg2 setup but a sidestepping alternative. I switched from using fcgi to gunicorn and also wrapped the self.connection.close() line with "try: self.connection.close(), except: pass". This also solved a 502 Bad Gateway problem I was having with nginx.

Also, it seems my site runs a little faster, which is always a sweet side effect.

Comment: For the record, this looks like [a bug in Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15802) which was fixed in version 1.4 (I believe).  Unless you are still using version 1.3 you probably don't need the explicit close attempt ([although it probably doesn't hurt, either](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17887))